# PhoneGap - Capturing photos doesnt work on Androids

Tags: jquery, cordova

I'm trying to capture a photo and access photo library, and since my console doesn't shows any error I dont know what to do to make it work. I'm using Phonegap, jquery and jquery mobile.

here's my html

```
<div data-role="content">
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
<button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
<img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
<img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
</div>
```

and my JS

```
var pictureSource;   
var destinationType;  

//
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

//
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
  //
  var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

  smallImage.style.display = 'block';

  //
  smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {

  var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');
  largeImage.style.display = 'block';
  largeImage.src = imageURI;
}

function capturePhoto() {
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}
function capturePhotoEdit() {
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}

function getPhoto(source) {
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}
function onFail(message) {
  alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Comment: which version of PhoneGap are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are programming an Android app and if you want to use hardware from the phone, you will have to implement rights for the app in the AndroidManifest.xml file:
these are some rights:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

paste it in the AndroidManifest.xml file just before:

```
<application>
```

normally you can find all the permissions on the web, try to search for the official phonegap book.